# How to get shipping quote in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

- I added two products to my cart and proceeded for checkout.
- I the customer from canada and the store belongs to US
- When I place my order am Unable to get shipping quote instead am getting this message

> Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time.

Can someone suggest me, what changes should I do in magento admin at shipping methods? or where should I make changes? Just please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check country Canada also in 'Ship to specific country' section from shipping method in admin.
[image]

If you are third party module please check all settings thats allow for countries.

Also check options in Go to

```
1)System ->> Configuration
2)Click on the “General” button in the left side menu pane
3)Click on the “Store Information” and fill in the Store Name, Store Contact Telephone, and Store contact Address
4)Open the section labeled "Countries Options"
5)Select the Default Country from the drop down menu
6)By default, all countries are allowed to access your store. If you wish to block a specific country from acessing your store, find the country in the "Allow Countries" list hold the CRTL key down and select the country. This will unhighlight the country and remove remove them from the list of allows countries.
```

Note:Check Country option

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but i did the same thing previously ,I changed all allowed countries to specific countries (like countries canada and US) though i didn't find shiping quote when i tried to place order from canada.

Comment: check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Flow below steps:**

1. Login to your site admin
2. Change the "Current Configuration Scope" (present on top of left sidebar) to "Main Website"
3. Go to System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods
4. Click "Table Rates"
5. Click "Export CSV" button for download "tablerates.csv" file
6. Change in downloaded CSV file per your requirement (Country, Region/State , Zip code, weight & Shipping Rates)
7. Import that exported file again. There is option to "Choose file". Browse the recently exported file and "Save Config"
8. Refresh cache from System -> Cache Management
9. After try to place order